# Reduced battery life with ubuntu 15.04

Tags: grub2, power-management, battery

I'm using a Lenovo Z-5070 Ci7.
I had a battery life of nearly 4 hours when I was using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After updating to Vived Vervet (15.04) my battery life is reduced to nearly 2 to 2.5 hours. It's almost halved. I use TLP and I've also changed the kernel boot mode options in `/etc/default/grub` and I still have a bad battery life. I'm not using extended graphics either. Is this a routine bug or is there something that can/should be done?

Comment: is this a dual VGA Laptop ?

Comment: Um, does TLP actually start ? Ubuntu 15.04 uses `systemd` so in `systemd` command to list running services is `systemctl status`

Comment: @Serg
TLp is running...  when i check tlp-stat
it says TLP-powersave = enabled... 
Or is there something more to it?

Comment: @FatMind
it's not...just an ordinary IdeaPad...

Comment: does the laptop use a graphics card? Is it one of the hybrid kinds of cards? Also, I've had issues with TLP in the past.

Comment: Nope... Bubble bee is off.... I'm using intel graphics itself.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed reduced battery life from like 5hrs to 2hrs max. Did some research and installed TLP. That kind of helped but not much. Some people advised to downgrade to kernel from 14.10 but I didn't want to do it.

Instead, I preferred to update to kernel 4. Installing it manually didn't do it so I did some research and found the script that works for whatever version you've got. I downloaded it from https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater and installed it. Than on next reboot info of new available kernel appeared so I run it:

```
sudo /tmp/kernel-update
```

Reboot and voila. back to 5-6hrs battery life with TLP enabled and nvidia drivers using intel integrated graphics card (power saving mode). happy days

oh btw my specs:

- laptop dell 7537
- Intel i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- 8GB ram
- Ubuntu 15.04
- kernel 4.0.0-040000-generic
- graphics card nvidia gforce 750m 2gb dedicated ram